# Printing to console when implementing a single Flutter page in iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, dart

**What I am trying to do:**
I am working on an app that is currently written in native iOS and Android (Swift and Kotlin). We are wanting to gradually migrate these two apps into one code base via replacing individual native app pages with Flutter pages until we have a full Flutter app. When building the current, mostly Swift project on Xcode, the iOS app is using `FlutterEngine`s to present individual Flutter pages and the Dart and Swift files are communicating via `MethodChannel`s.

I am wanting to print to the console from within the Dart file of the individual Flutter page that is displayed in my iOS app.

**What I've tried:**
I've tried printing to the console by making use of the `print()` and `log()` methods in my Dart files. I've also tried running `flutter attach` from the terminal while running the iOS project in question and am successfully attaching to the app (I'm able to hot restart/reload), but my Dart files are still not printing to the console. What methods have you all used to print to the console from Dart files being accessed in an iOS project via `FlutterEngine`?

Comment: Does it work on the Kotlin version? Have you tried `flutter run --verbose`?

Comment: We've not tried the Kotlin version, but I will try. We aren't using `flutter run` to launch the app because it is actually an Xcode project (written 90%+ in Swift) that injects a few flutter pages using `FlutterEngine`. So we are building it like a typical Swift/Xcode project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have always used Print() to print to the console.

Maybe there is some issues with the data to be printed.
Just an opinion, I may be wrong.

Comment: My coworker mentioned they use `print()` as well and it would print to the Xcode console. We were calling `print('test')` just to get it working, so wasn't likely the data's fault. We also ensured I was using the master Flutter channel and we also observed logs via running `flutter logs` in the terminal, no luck. :(

Comment: In most cases, print works fine, I'm still working on figuring out what my issue was. Once I have, I will specify what was causing it more in my question.